# Read formatted text file from excel with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a huge text file with lots of numbers divided into different sections and I want to extract only certain values. It is something like this

```
step 1
787268 4.29430E-01
787269 4.05248E-01
787270 3.99742E-01
787271 3.99136E-01
787272 3.98422E-01
787273 3.97019E-01
787274 3.95237E-01
step 2
787268 4.29430E-01
787269 4.05248E-01
787270 3.99742E-01
787271 3.99136E-01
787272 3.98422E-01
787273 3.97019E-01
787274 3.95237E-01
```

I want to copy into my excel file only the two columns in the step 2 section.
So I need a VBA code that allows me to search for a particular string and after it finds it copy and paste all the raws until the next step.

Any pieces of code?

Thanks
Stefano

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [website](https://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/copy-data-from-one-range-another/) to help you find what you need, a simple Google search can go a long way.

I would suggest using an if found section to find the spot where you need to copy over.

Ex.

```
If (Range("A1").Value = "YOUR TEXT HERE") Then
    '''' COPY OVER DATA
End If
```